# Looking for customers that have not done service business with us in the last 3 years

Tags: sql, max, dateadd

I'm trying to find the most recent customer invoice that is older than 3 years old but after checking my results against the actual records there are invoices in the service header table that are newer than 3 years old.

Using SQL Management Studio

```
    select [No_] as 'Customer No.', 
    sih.[Name],  
    max(sih.[No_]) as 'Last Service Invoice No.', 
    max(sih.[Posting Date]) as 'Last Service Order'
    from [Service Invoice Header]sih 
    left join [Customer] c on sih.[Customer No_] = c.[No_]


    group by c.[No_], sih.name

    having max(sih.[Posting Date]) <  DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())
    order by sih.name
```

I expect to get the last service invoice posting date older than 3 years old for each customer that I have invoiced.

Comment: So what's wrong?  You need to tell us what your existing code is doing that it shouldn't be.

Comment: After checking for actual invoices there are some that are newer than three years old in the actual records.

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample, your actual result and your expected result

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want:

```
select sih.*
from [Service Invoice Header] sih 
where sih.[Posting Date] = (select max(sih2.[Posting Date])
                            from [Service Invoice Header] sih2
                            where sih2.[Customer No_] = sih.[No_] and
                                  sih2.[Posting Date]) < DATEADD(YEAR, -3, GETDATE())
                           );
```

You are not selecting columns from the customers table, so it does not seem needed.  If you really need it, you can add it in to the outer query.